# driver for Ethernet Adapter: cdc_ether: no symbol version for module_layout

Tags: usb, ethernet, driver

I want to use TP-LINK USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter on my pi, but I have an error about the driver:

```
cdc_ether: no symbol version for module_layout.
```

dmesg:

```
[  210.182816] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[  210.269869] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0601
[  210.269899] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  210.269922] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[  210.269943] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: TP-LINK
[  210.269963] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 000001000000
[  210.302433] cdc_ether: no symbol version for module_layout

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb (the last one)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0601
```

uname -a:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.16-rt13-v7+ #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Thu Mar 17 15:08:02 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

could anyone help me?